# LevelDB в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Писал на PHP используя MySQL. Пытаюсь написать сайт на Express.

Мне нужно реализовать систему авторизации / регистрации используя LevelDb. 
Столкнулся с проблемой, что уроков вообще никаких нет.

Подскажите как можно реализовать данную систему: допустим чтобы данные хранились как

key: Ник Игрока; values: пароль, почта и тд.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Могу подсказать один скринкаст по LevelDB на youtube [вот здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcILF2wfzYk).
Тут достаточно подробно изложено и я сам смотрел для интереса. Но дальше интереса пока дело не зашло )

Comment: Проблема в том, что если база пустая, то не ошибок, не предупреждений не выводит при использование createReadStream()